# css and images not loading

Tags: asp.net, css, image, iis

i have uploaded my asp.net 4 web forms site to my testing server. all the database connectivity issue is resolved and its working perfctly but i am having problem the css and the images are not showing neither localy on the server nor if i try to access it from the external link.

i am using master pages. (if this help in anyway )

i have tryed to hard code the styles into a page. they have appeared i think there is something with the path on server i have to create

i have double checked the css path and the images path they are correct but still they are not showing. any idea?

Thank you 4 the help

Comment: What response are you getting from the web server for the css/images? Are you seeing any error messages?

Comment: no i am not getting any error msg

Comment: Can you post the CSS for the images?

Comment: If you try to view one of the css files in a browser by the url, do you get an error message or just a blank 200 response?

Comment: Did you forget to make a virtual directory/IIS application on your production server?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem two minutes ago. Here's the solution.

All you have to do is run ‘optionalfeature’ command and make sure ‘Static Content’ option is checked.
[image]